# Custom made frozen_inference_graph.pb not working?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am working on a license plate detection software. I trained TensorFlow object detection API on custom made license plate dataset in google collaboratory. After that, I downloaded frozen_inference_graph.pb from the training folder which is an end result after training. Initially, I used a saved_model.pb which was downloaded from TensorFlow hub and it works fine but now I renamed this frozen_graph_inference.pb to saved_model.pb and when I used it is giving me an error

CODE I USED FOR LOADING THE SAVED_MODEL

> ```
> #picking an object detection module
> ```
>
> module_handle="Models/"
>   detector = hub.load(module_handle).signatures['default']

Here models is the directory for where i store all the models.
When i use my custom made model i am getting this error

> File "objectDetection.py", line 2, in 
>       from helperFunctions import *
>     File "C:\MachineLearning\helperFunctions.py", line 89, in 
>       detector = hub.load(module_handle).signatures['default']
>     File "C:\MachineLearning\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\signature_serialization.py", line 195, in **getitem**
>       return self._signatures[key]
>   KeyError: 'default'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: here I understood that a key named default is not found. It is true but I searched the entire file for that key but it is not available. So what can I place instead of 'default'

Answer (score 0):

A [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) is a different file format than an old-school [GraphDef](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/GraphDef). They cannot be exchanged like that.